# Cannot Run Unit Tests for Windows Store apps in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I can't seem to run unit tests for Windows store apps using Visual Studio 2012.

I have gone through the following steps in order to configure my application.

1. I create a windows store project.  I build it and get it to run just fine.
2. I than right click on the solution and click Add > New Project.   From the 'Add New Project Menu' I select the project template 'Unit Test Library (Windows Store apps) and click okay creating the project.
3. I create a basic unit test that looks something like the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTestLibrary1
{
  [TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      string a = "a";
      string b = "b";

      Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note as per the [instructions found on the MSDN website here I have not built the Unit Test project yet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh440545.aspx)

4 - I open the Visual Studio test explore which displays the following.

[image]

5 - I proceed to build the entire solution (below is the build output)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vevo.pushclient, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: UnitTestLibrary1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  UnitTestLibrary1 -> C:\Source\simple_push_client\vevo.pushclient\UnitTestLibrary1\bin\Debug\UnitTestLibrary1.dll
1>  vevo.pushclient -> C:\Source\simple_push_client\vevo.pushclient\vevo.pushclient\bin\Debug\vevo.pushclient.exe
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The following was the output from Tests, I tried googling the error but could not find any helpful answers

```
------ Discover test started ------
MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class 'UnitTestLibrary1.UnitTest1' of assembly 'C:\Source\simple_push_client\vevo.pushclient\UnitTestLibrary1\bin\Debug\UnitTestLibrary1.dll'. Reason Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework.TestCategoryBaseAttribute.get_TestCategory()'..
NUnit 0.97.0.0 discovering tests is started
NUnit 0.97.0.0 discovering test is finished
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.1800223) ==========
```

The Test Explorer still showed the same message as before the build that stated 'Build your solution to discover all available tests....

Even so I tried clicking run all.

This resulted in the following output for the build

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And no output for Tests

Needless to say no tests were shown as having been run, passed, skipped, or failed in the test explorer.

I ensured that the configuration Properties of the UnitTest project were set to build and deploy and attempted to build using each platform configuration (Any CPU, x86, and x4)

[image]

Comment: The link you provided said something about updating your manifest. Did you do that? Stupid question: Did you try restarting VS?

Comment: Yes I tried restarted VS, even restarted the whole computer for kicks.  As far as updating the manifest it is an option step. "The capabilities you select should only include capabilities that are necessary for the Windows Store unit test".  That being said I did try updating it just to see if if would make a difference but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding?

Comment: Yes I have tried rebuilding

Comment: As a Unit Test Library, does it not need to have the Windows Store App as a reference/dependency? Make sure the build order and dependency list reflects this.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that you are missing an attribute on your test methods...

MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class 'UnitTestLibrary1.UnitTest1' of assembly 'C:\Source\simple_push_client\vevo.pushclient\UnitTestLibrary1\bin\Debug\UnitTestLibrary1.dll'. Reason Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework.TestCategoryBaseAttribute.get_TestCategory()'..

Not sure why, it shouldn't be required.  But add the attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTestLibrary1
{
  [TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("tests")]    <! -- Added Attribute -->
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      string a = "a";
      string b = "b";

      Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

The Category can be whatever you want.  Not sure why its doing that, Category should be an optional parameter.